# ATtiny85 sharing SPI and I2C pins

Tags: i2c, spi, attiny85

I have an [ATtiny85](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/ATtiny85) sending messages via LoRa over SPI and I've hooked up a BME280 on I2C which I'm using with the [TinyBME280](https://github.com/technoblogy/tiny-bme280) library. Everything is fine until I read the temperature, which then hangs the system.

The BME280 uses `PB7` and `PB5` which are also used by LoRa for `SCK` and `MOSI` respectively. I thought ending the `Wire` session and using `LoRa.begin()` on each loop iteration would solve the issue but it just hangs while reading the temperature.

```
  Wire.begin();
  BME280setup();
  int32_t temperature = BME280temperature();
  Wire.end();
  ...
  LoRa.begin();
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  ...
  LoRa.endPacket();
  ...
```

is it possible to share SPI and I2C pins in this way, or is it just a case of the ATtiny85 not having enough pins for this type of application?

Comment: I want to make sure the BME280 is working properly on your setup, becouse you did not mention that you can read the temperature seperately. Are you able to read temperature using a code that does not use LoRa at all (but while LoRa is connected to your Attiny)?

Comment: Do you have to use the same pins then? Or can you initialize only one interface at a time for use and then deinitialize it? Or use bit-bang I2C or SPI? Both interfaces may use the single hardware USI and I2C comms might get mixed up if same pins talk SPI.

Comment: keeping the LoRa module attached but commenting out all the code is the same. Reading the temperature hangs. It should turn on an LED on PB3 then off after 2s but the LED is on permanently, meaning the temperature call doesn't return.

Comment: using the LED, it hangs on BME280setup() when it tries to talk to the module. I think I'll just have to look for another library or do it myself

Comment: Are you using any of the timers for anythning else? Just in case the BME280 library fails to use them or relies on the default config? Maybe not related to the problem, but BME280 also supports SPI-mode, if you have any unused pins for CS.

Comment: What are you building, btw? I know a commercial solution that does a similar thing.

Comment: Please post your circuit diagram.

Comment: thanks for the helpful pointers. I think I'll write my own driver for the module as no library/core combination I've tried works.